# Determining child index of a Nokogiri element

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, parent-child

if I have a Nokogiri::XML::Element, how do I figure its child index in relation to its parent?  That is:

```
<foo>     <-- parent
  <bar/>  <-- 1st child
  <bar/>  <-- 2nd child
</foo>
```

In Javascriptland, jQuery has [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/), but Nokogiri doesn't.  Nokogiri does provide a [path](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-path) method, but that returns an XPath string like `"/foo/bar[2]"` and truncates `bar[1]` to `bar` to boot, so turning that back into a number is a little hairy:

```
element.path.split('/').last.slice(/[0-9]+/) || '1'          # quick'n'dirty
element.path.split('/').last.slice(/\[([0-9]+)\]/, 1) || '1' # a bit safer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
element.parent.children.index(element)
```

To consider only non-text nodes:

```
element.xpath('../*').index(element)
```

To consider only bar nodes:

```
element.xpath('../bar').index(element)
```

Comment: Note that this will include Text nodes in the list.

Comment: Beautiful!  @Phrogz, point taken, but that's trivially fixed by using element_children instead (as in your answer).

Answer (score 3):

Technique 1: Find my siblings, see where I fit within them:

```
idx = element.parent.element_children.index(element)

# Alternatively:
idx = element.parent.xpath('*').index(element)
```

Technique 2: Count the number of element (not text) nodes before me:

```
idx = element.xpath('count(preceding-sibling::*)').to_i

# Alternatively, if you want to waste time and memory:
# idx = element.xpath('preceding-sibling::*').length
```

**Technique 2 is measurably faster.**

Answer (score 1):

This selects nodes of the same element name and returns the index:

`element.parent.xpath(element.name).index(element)`